# unable to update element's attribute value who attribute is "name" and value is "attribute_mappings"

Tags: java, xml

I have my xml file and want to update one element's attribute's value

```
<PageLayout configType="partner" name="Attributes Mapping Options" order="5" resourceBundleKey="guixml_connector_attributeMappingOptionsPageLayout_Label">
    <Description resourceBundleKey="guixml_connector_attributeMappingOptions_Label" textLabel="Provide attribute mapping options for this connector"/>
    <AttributeMapping dataField="attribute_mappings" displayField="name" mode="create,edit" name="attribute_mappings" uuidField="id">
        <ComponentLabel resourceBundleKey="guixml_connector_attributeDetails_Label" textLabel="Enter attribute details"/>
          <Values addJsonHeaders="true">
                    <Url>/mga/attribute_sources</Url>
         </Values>              
        <NameHeading resourceBundleKey="guixml_connector_attributeName_Label" textLabel="Attribute Name"/>
        <SourceHeading resourceBundleKey="guixml_connector_attributeSource_Label" textLabel="Attribute Source"/>
    </AttributeMapping>
</PageLayout>
```

Here I want to update "AttributeMapping" tag. attribute `displayField="source_name"` instread of `displayField="name"`

here if this is only one element then  i can do it easily, but in my xml file there are multiple elements with the same attribute.

so i want to update only that tag whose `name="attribute_mappings"`

i have wrote below code for this but this seems a bad code because i have done same for loop 2 time.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(searchPath);
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node element = nodes.item(i);
    NamedNodeMap attributes = element.getAttributes();
    Map<String, String> attrMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int j = 0; j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
        Node attrItem = attributes.item(j);
        attrMap.put(attrItem.getNodeName(),
        attrItem.getNodeValue());
    }
    if (attrMap.get("name").equalsIgnoreCase(
    "attribute_mappings"))
    for (int j = 0; j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
        Node attrItem = attributes.item(j);
        if (attrItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(
        "displayField")) {
        attrItem.setNodeValue("source_name");
    }

}
```

Is there any other way of doing same.

Comment: One can make one single XPath expression for the attribute and change it. Seach "cheat sheet xpath" or better an XPath example.

Comment: is there a possibility that your xml tree is correctly modified but you have not write it in a file and that's the reason why you don't see the modifications ?

Comment: No. I have all permission to read and write the file.

Comment: that's not a permission problem. In this code, in my opinion you just modify the Java object. I'm not sure you write the modification in the file.

Comment: I have wrote the modification in file. using TransformerFactory and Transformer

Comment: Also you didn't get my question. I just want  another way of writing this above code. My file is updating and code is working fine. But i have used same for loop 2 times that's why i am asking another way of doing above code. I have done code like and adjustment. Is there any other way in Dom parser to do this

Comment: i check ur code it is working fine. so you want next.